# How to get the MVC 3 or 4 template in MonoDevelop?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, monodevelop, archlinux

Just started to play around with Mono and MonoDevelop on Archlinux and I can with no problem create a new ASP.NET MVC 2 project and run it. But I can't figure out how could I create an MVC 3 or 4 project.
I read on a [forum](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/ASP-NET-MVC-3-Project-Template-td4650368.html) that there is MVC 3 project template in MonoDevelop, but it has some dependencies in order to show it in the New Solution.. dialog.
So my question is: How can I get the MVC 3 or 4 solution template on when I run MonoDevelop on Linux?

Comment: What version of MonoDevelop are you running?

Comment: MonoDevelop 3.0.3.5 and I have Mono 2.10.8.

Comment: Mono 2.10.x does not support MVC4, but it does support MVC3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the the MVC 3 template to show up you need to install Mono version 2.11.3 or higher. In Archlinux you can do that by installing the mono-git from AUR repository.

Comment: That's kind of strange.  MVC3 works fine in the latest 2.10.x releases, why does it require 2.11.x?

Comment: It might support it, but it doesn't provides the template. Unfortunately don't have a simple site with MVC3 so I could have tested it.

Answer (score 0):

The Asp.Net MVC templates tweaked for mono are here:
https://www.cafe-encounter.net/p1510/asp-net-mvc4-net-framework-version-4-5-c-razor-template-for-mono-on-mac-and-linux

where “tweaked” means, e.g. fixing case-sensitive filename issues.