# how to add asp.net mvc templates for monodevelop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, monodevelop

I'm on archlinux using mono 4.0.4 and monodevelop 5.9.

By following the Getting started guide I noticed there are some scaffolding options missing, I see some nuget packages for scaffolding but installing them didn't do much.

SO has these two questions :
[How to get the MVC 3 or 4 template in MonoDevelop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530010/how-to-get-the-mvc-3-or-4-template-in-monodevelop)
[Developing ASP.NET MVC using MonoDevelop on MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891329/developing-asp-net-mvc-using-monodevelop-on-mac)

The latter is for Mac and both of them are outdated As I'm talking about asp.net mvc 5 here.

searching didn't reveal anything apart from the Nuget packages I added and I can't see any addins in the add-in manager for this(prefer not to use beta or alpha addins).

So what to do to get these ?
P.S:
I know I can get them with yoeman but I like to use monodevelop, if yoeman can be integrated with monodevelop So I can see options like "model with view and controller" scaffolding(that is a CRUD ready application) then I'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are talking about the templates that are available in an ASP.NET MVC application when you select Add View or Add Controller. If this is not the case then please update your question with more information.

The templates listed when adding a new view or controller to an ASP.NET MVC project are taken from t4 template files (.tt) in the following folders:

- AddIns\AspNet\CodeTemplates\CSharp\AddController
- AddIns\AspNet\CodeTemplates\CSharp\AddView\Razor

You can add extra .tt files into this folder and they will be displayed in the Add View and Add Controller dialog.

Out of the box MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio only has a few t4 templates available so you would need to either write your own or find some from elsewhere. SharpDevelop has more [T4 templates](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/tree/master/src/AddIns/BackendBindings/AspNet.Mvc/Project/ItemTemplates/CSharp/CodeTemplates) or MVC which could probably be used but may require some modification.

Comment: yes that's what I'm talking about, I saw those .tt files when I added scaffolding packages but they didn't add anything to the menus(clicking on  Views folder then Add->View didn't show beyond what was there already)

Comment: What do you mean by adding scaffolding packages? Adding a nuget package would not change the templates available